# Adobe AIR Mobile on iOS - processing text very slow

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript, air, text-processing

I am writing an iOS app in Flash Builder 4.6 that will need to process a large text file.  So far, I am just trying to get the version information from the file, a simple task that runs very fast in the simulator but takes a very long time (on the order of 10 seconds) on my iPad 2.

As the file is large (about 11MB), I am trying to only read far enough into the file to get the version data.  Is it possible that the filestream loads the whole file into memory anyway?  If so, how do I avoid that?

Note that the code works correctly, and displays the correct version info.

Any advice on how to speed it up would be greatly appreciated.

The file being processed can be found here: http://oanda.sca.org:80/oanda.db

The code is as follows:

Calling code:

```
protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
{
    var DT:DatabaseTools = new DatabaseTools();
    var version:String;
    //Get version information from local file:
    version = DT.GetLocalVer("oanda.db");               
    lblLclVer.text=version;
}
```

Actual function:

```
public function GetLocalVer(fileName:String):String
{
    var out:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var line_Out:String;
    var char:int;
    var line:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
    var lineString:String;
    var result:String = "Error";

    stream.open(file,FileMode.READ);

    var found:Boolean=false;

    while((stream.bytesAvailable > 0) && !found)
    {
        char=stream.readByte();
        if(String.fromCharCode(char) == "\n")
        {
            //reset the line
            out=line;
            line = new ByteArray();

            //process the line to see if its the version info.
            lineString=out.toString();  //since the version line never has UTF characters, convert it to a regular string
            if(lineString.length > 25)  //Any line shorter than this can't be the version line
            {
                var startOfLine:String = lineString.substr(0,17);
                if(startOfLine == " ||C|Last update:")
                {
                    result = lineString.substr(19,6);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            line.writeByte(char);
        }
    }
    stream.close();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the filestream loads the complete file. I'm not sure why you'd want to read that big of a file (how many lines does that document have anyways? A textfile with 11MB seems rather large) just to check it's version number? Is there no way to split the information the file contains?

Comment: Checking version number is just the first task I started programming, to familiarize myself with text processing in this environment, the rest of the app is all about extracting various data from that file.  The file come to me as is from an external source.  I've thought about converting it to a SQL DB, but the types of searches I need to run against it (mostly regex type of text searches) don't lend themselves well to that (especially since the AIR implementation ofnSQLite doesn't support regex).